# Retrieve the position of a clicked button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, everything is on the question. I have a clickEvent on one of my button and i want to retrieve the position of this button when i click on it.

Actually i retrieve the position event.pageX but it's not really what i want...

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $( "#dM1").click( function(event) {
        dropMenu('dropMenu1', event.pageX);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(this)[.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) will have information regarding the object that was clicked within your event handler relative to the offset parent. $(this)[.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset) has positioning information relative to the document.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude ! Exactly what i wanted.

Comment: @Sindar Just keep in mind if you have an element positioned in a non-static container, i.e. a parent container that is position: relative, etc, then the return from .position() will change. In those cases, if you need the item position on the document, use .offset().